# Data modeling for nosql database for Quiz app

Tags: firebase, nosql

Hi I'm currently developing a quiz app for Android with Firestore database. Since I'm new to Nosql, I wanted to ask about opinion of my data model.

So I want to have two main trees in my database. One that stores questions and one that stores users.
So the first one I imagine like that:

```
mainCategory
    subCategory
        question
            -questionText
            -answerA
            -answerB
            -...
```

The other one with users:

```
user
    -email, password and other personal info
    mainCategory
        subCategory
            answeredQuestions
                -questionID
    test
        questions
            -questionID
            -answer
```

My motivation:

Questions is saved like that because user will be able to choose specific categories and subcategories, so this way I won't have to load unnecessary data.

I want to store questions IDs on users in the same manner they're saved in question tree so that its easier to create tests without questions user already answered. It is also important for me to know what percentage of all questions in certain category were already answered by user.

I want to store unfinished tests on user so that he can come back to unfinished tests.

Thanks in advance for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

@szymon Balcer

I was wondering if you decided on a firestore data model?
I'm dealing with a similar situation.
I have a bank of questions that are organized into one of 10 or so categories and each category can have a couple of sub-categories.
A user can select 1 to 10 categories and the total number of quiz questions, then take a quiz. 
A user shouldn't see the same question twice (until going thru entire question bank)
A user can see how many total questions attempted, got right, got wrong across all quizzes and what they scored in each category.

So I was thinking of the following structure:

```
questions
  -questionId
     question: "..."
     category: "category"
     subCategory: "sub-category"

student
   -studentId
      quizs
        -quizId
           numberOfQuestions: "10"
           categories: 
           number Correct: ...
      answeredQuestions
         -answeredQuestionId
            quizId: *id to group as a quiz*
            questionId: *id to ref question content*
            quizQuestionNumber: *which question in quiz 4th question out of 10*
            category: *from question content*
            subcategory: *from question content*
            isCorrect: boolean *if they got question correct*
```

But i'm not 100% sure..
have you made any progress?

thanks
drew

Comment: Hi Drew!
I'm going with described data model so far, but i'm still waiting for suggestion.